# MySQL using the UUID_SHORT() function

Tags: mysql

If I use the UUID_SHORT() function in an INSERT statement, how do I make sure the UUID it creates has not already been used in the table before, does it automatically check that, and regenerate a UUID on collision?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of `UUID_SHORT()` is [guaranteed](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short) to be unique if the following conditions hold:

- The `server_id` of the current host is unique among your set of master and slave servers
- `server_id` is between 0 and 255
- You don't set back your system time for your server between mysqld restarts
- You do not invoke `UUID_SHORT()` on average more than 16 million times per second between mysqld restarts

Comment: Ok so if I am only using it every few days or more it should always remain unique correct?

Answer (score 2):

Add a UNIQUE constraint to the column, then you won't be able to insert a duplicate value.